# Webpage text-only into PDF with Python PDFkit

Tags: python, pdfkit

I am trying to convert a large section of a website into a pdf. I can convert one page with pdfkit, but I do not want the images on the website, just the text. Is there a way to do this with pdfkit? I have been searching google for the last half hour looking for a solution, but can only find information about getting pictures, not excluding them.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

This information can be found in the [documentation for "wkhtmltopdf"](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt).
This tool has a `--no-images` option.

The [PyPI page for pdfkit](https://pypi.org/project/pdfkit/) explains how to set options when using the Python package.

So this is what you are looking for:

```py
import pdfkit
options = {
    'no-images':True
}
pdfkit.from_url('https://www.google.com/','out.pdf',options=options)
```